# How to find the base of an isosceles triangle with the angles and legs

Tags: geometry, triangles

I want to find the base of an isosceles triangle with base angles of 54.5 degrees and legs with the lengths of 43 with geometric relationships.

Comment: Please DON'T SHOUT. It helped to frame the question if you showed what you tried and where you got stuck.

Comment: What does "GEOMETRICAL RELATIONSHIPS" mean, exactly? In any case, you will need trigonometry. Consider the cosine of the base angle.

Comment: Hint: check out the [law of sines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_sines).

Comment: Is there any way to solve this without trigonometry?

Comment: In the end you'll still need to calculate the (equivalent of some) trig functions for $54.5^\circ$ and  $71^\circ$.

Comment: There is no way without trig. Don't fear trig. If you have a right triange with hypotenuse 1 and an angle of X. The the legs will be specific lengths. Trig is nothing more or less then a list of all the leg values. If the angle is X the leg on the opposite side is sin X. That's a definition. The side next to the angle is cosine X. That's a definition. Cut the triangle in half into two right triangles. The right triangles will have hypotenuse 43 and an angle 54.5. So $1/2 base = 43* \cos 54.5$ plug that into a calculator and you are done.

Comment: 54.5 is just a little bit less than 60 so this will be just a little squatter than an equilateral triangle.  So the base will be just a bit bigger than 43.  The exact value is $2*43*\cos 54.5$ .  Cos 54.5 is going to be a little more than 1/2.  Plug it into a calculator for the exact value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this picture http://mathworld.wolfram.com/images/eps-gif/Trigonometry_700.gif

Imagine that $\theta = 90-54.5= 35.5$.

This is a picture of your triangle cut in half, laid on its side, and shrunk to $1/43$ it's size.

We want to know what is the length of the side labeled "$\sin \theta $" is.

Your answer will be twice that multiplied by $43$.

So we plug it it into a calculator and get $\sin 35.5 = 0.58070295571093976105008.... $

So multiply that by $2$ and you will have the base of an isoceles triangle with legs of $1$.

Multiply that by $43$ and you will have the base of your tringle.

So the answer is $49.940454191140819450...... $.